# F# Trying to access ConfigurationManager

Tags: f#, configurationmanager

I'm building a small project to understand F# better.  As part of it, I want a function "myAppSettings" that uses System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager to read settings from the AppSettings.config file.  I put this in a separate file in my solution called myAppSettings and it looks like this:

```
namespace foo.bar
open System
open System.Configuration

module myAppSettings =
    let read key mandatory = 
        let appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
        let value = appSettings key
        if mandatory && String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) then
            failwith "bad hombres"
        value
```

This does not compile however,  I get the error:

> Error 1   The namespace or module 'ConfigurationManager' is not defined

I know that that object is in System.Configuration (use it all the time from C#) so I must have syntax wrong somewhere, but where?

I also tried:

```
let appSettings = new ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
let value = appSettings key
```

which then found the ConfigurationManager (the new keyword helped) but then objected to the "let value":

> Error 1   Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in
>   expression

I want to understand the two error messages and the right way to access the settings in the app.config file.

Comment: This question isn't about `ConfigurationManager` not being available in the current context, it is about accessing `ConfigurationManager` from F#.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is with how you are accessing the `ConfigurationManager`:

```
namespace foo.bar
open System
open System.Configuration

module myAppSettings =
    let read key mandatory = 
        //let appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
        //let value = appSettings key
        let value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item(key)
        if mandatory && String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) then
            failwith "bad hombres"
        value
```

If you want to keep the two-part access, try it like this:

```
let appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
let value = appSettings.Item(key)
```

Comment: That worked! Though I had to add a type annotation to "key" since it could be either a string or an integer.  Make sense?

Comment: @user1443098 yep, that does make sense